# Gender being changed to "Directory server" on Google Contacts insert

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

I'm using the gdata-python-client library (http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to insert contacts into a Google account. When I set the gender like this:

```
google_contact.gender = gdata.contacts.data.Gender(text="Male")
```

it's actually being set on the contact in the field "Directory server".

Any ideas why this might be happening?

In case it affects anything, my code is running on a Google App Engine development server.

Comment: It might help to mention any diagnostic techniques you have attempted yourself, and the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verily, I say unto you, this is indeed a bug in the gData client. Here is the [line containing the bug](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/contacts/data.py#119), and here is the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=590) I filed concerning the issue, and [here's a patch](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=591) I've submitted that solves the issue

The specifics of patching one's local copy of the library while the upstream fix is pending is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: And the patch has been accepted at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/detail?r=9676d3b1059bcbbcf7e358abb3450cedf40546a6, so a fresh install via the usual tools should pick up the fix.

Comment: He looked upon the answer, and he saw that it was good. 50 rep to you!

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bug in gdata library. At least that's  how I see it. Not a google-contact expert here

consider this:

```
>>> print gdata.contacts.data.City(text="Foo")
<ns0:city xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008">Foo</ns0:city>
```

while Gender returns this:

```
>>> print gdata.contacts.data.Gender(text="Male")
<ns0:directoryServer xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008">Male</ns0:directoryServer>
```

Of course you can alter the tag property of Gender object manually:

```
>>> g = gdata.contacts.data.Gender(text="Male")
>>> g.tag='gender'
>>> print g
<ns0:gender xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008">Male</ns0:gender>
```

Hope this helps